# AWS Route53 naked domain doesn't work

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I bought my domain (banuka.com) from the `Namecheap`. And created an `AWS` Route53 public hosted zone.

And also I added the `Nameservers` copied from that above hosted zone to the Namescheap DNS servers.

And I created a simple nginx server in an `EC2` and created 2 records;

```
banuka.com              A          <IP-OF-EC2>
nginx.banuka.com        A          <IP-OF-EC2>
```

My problem is, `http://nginx.banuka.com` works but not the `banuka.com`. Accessing just `http://banuka.com` give me "This site can’t be reached" in browser.

Can someone help me to fix this?

When I try to dig the `banuka.com`, it gives the following result

```
➜  ~ dig banuka.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> banuka.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 32429
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;jananath.com.          IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
banuka.com.     454 IN  SOA ns-920.awsdns-51.net. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400

;; Query time: 41 msec
;; SERVER: 2a02:2457:30c:101::11#53(2a02:2457:30c:101::11)
;; WHEN: Tue Jun 27 15:31:54 CEST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 122
```

Can someone help me to understand what is going on?

Comment: When I use MXToolbox to query for that domain or the subdomain I get a result that it's a CNAME for traff-3.hugedomains.com . Maybe you haven't delegated DNS to Route53 yet.

Comment: I still see the NS server records as being from "hugedomains.com" so you will want to double check that you made the change in Namecheap. If it looks right in Namecheap it may be a propagation delay, but for most domains I would expect to see the changes after nearly 24 hours.